# TableView Cell only refreshes when its scrolled on and off the screen (Firebase observe)

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, uitableview

I have a tableview that updates using the observe listener with Firebase.

If I say, change some data, the actual data structure is updated, and I do call tableView.reloadData(), but it only loads the data into the cells when you scroll the cell off the screen visible in the table, and then bring it back on. It's like it then draws the cell now it's come on and off but with the updated data.

How do I make this dynamic?

```
 func getProblems(){
    print("getting problems")

    let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference(withPath: "problems")

    ref.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in

        self.problems  = []
        var newProblems: Array<Problem> = []

        let json = JSON(snapshot.value)
        //print(json)


        for (key, value) in json {

            var problemReceived = json[key]

            var newProblem = Problem(id: "", user_id: "", title: "", message: "", status: 0, category: 0, image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "NoImage"), commentCount: 0, distance: 0, date: Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 5 * 60), user_name: "Derek Sibling", comments: [])

            newProblem.id = problemReceived["id"].stringValue
            newProblem.user_id = problemReceived["user_id"].stringValue
            newProblem.title = problemReceived["title"].stringValue
            newProblem.message = problemReceived["message"].stringValue
            newProblem.status = problemReceived["status"].intValue
            newProblem.category = problemReceived["category"].intValue
            newProblem.status = problemReceived["status"].intValue
            newProblem.distance =  Double(arc4random_uniform(9) + 1)

            newProblem.image_url  = problemReceived["image_url"].stringValue
            newProblem.downloadImage()
            newProblem.getComments()

            if(newProblem.status != 1){
                newProblems.append(newProblem)


            }

            self.counter = self.counter + 1
            if(self.counter == Int(snapshot.childrenCount)){
                //self.comments = tempComments
            }
        }


        self.problems = newProblems
        self.problems = self.problems.shuffled()

        self.tableView.reloadData()
    })

}





func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell  = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for : indexPath) as! CustomCell


            cell.titleLabel.text = problems[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].getTitle()
            cell.descriptionLabel.text = problems[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].getMessage()

           cell.statusLabel.text = problems[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].calculateSolved()
            cell.messageCountLabel.text = "\(problems[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].comments.count)"
            cell.distanceLabel.text = "\(problems[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].getDistance())km"
            cell.problemImage.image = problems[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].getImage()
    return cell
}



func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    var cell:CustomCell = cell as! CustomCell
    cell.messageCountLabel.text = "\(problems[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].comments.count)"
}
```

Comment: Use the UITableViewController class instead of UIViewController. Because they're override functions, I mean the data source methods

Comment: I didn't get your problem could you better explain

Comment: Reloading the table view calls the same code that is run when the cell goes off and comes back on the screen. The only thing I can think of is that the data is being updated after you call `reloadData()`. I assume `downloadImage()` and `getComments()` are asynchronous, correct? That means comments and a new image (if the URL changed), won't be available until later.

Comment: Yes Dave you're right, but however long I leave it they dont update. I scroll the cell off and onto the screen and it reloads though. 

Should I be using UITableViewController as Mannopson suggested? 

You may be right that its being updated before the data is returned, but however long I leave it it never refreshes until its been on and off? 
What do you think? 

I really appreciate all your help!!

Comment: any more advice @DaveWeston ? still struggling with it!